# How to attach AWS Lambda fn to EXISTING vpc using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**TLDR**: We deploy Lambda functions using Terraform.  A new lambda requires VPC attachment to an existing VPC.  How do I define this network attachment in terraform?  My current solution passes all terraform steps, but when inspect my Lambda in the console, it's not attached to any VPC.

I found [this article Deploy AWS Lambda to VPC with Terraform](https://www.maxivanov.io/deploy-aws-lambda-to-vpc-with-terraform/) insightful, but the example involves adding a **new** VPC (with subnets, security groups, etc.) as opposed to attaching to **existing** VPC, existing subnets, security groups etc.

Here's my current solution.  From my project's main.tf I call a module...

```
module "lambda" {
    source = "git::https://corpsource.io/corp-cloud-platform-team/corpcloudv2/terraform/lambda-modules.git?ref=dev" 
    lambda_name = var.name
    lambda_role = "arn:aws:iam::${var.ACCOUNT}:role/${var.lambda_role}"
    lambda_handler = var.handler
    lambda_runtime = var.runtime
    default_lambda_timeout = var.timeout
    ACCOUNT = var.ACCOUNT
    vpc_subnet_ids = "${var.SUBNET_IDS}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = "${var.SECURITY_GROUP_IDS}"
}
```

And here is the module:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  filename         = "lambda_package.zip"
  function_name    = var.lambda_name
  role             = var.lambda_role
  handler          = var.lambda_handler
  runtime          = var.lambda_runtime
  memory_size      = 256
  timeout          = var.default_lambda_timeout
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("lambda_code/lambda_package.zip")
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = var.vpc_subnet_ids
    security_group_ids = var.vpc_security_group_ids
  }
}
```

It passes all Terraform steps without error, and yet doesn't appear to attach my Lambda to a VPC.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Output of `Terraform Plan`:

```
$ terraform plan
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.lambda_function: Refreshing state... [id=create-vault-entry]
module.lambda_iam.aws_iam_policy.base_policy: Refreshing state... [id=arn:aws:iam::############:policy/create-vault-entry-role]
module.lambda_iam.aws_iam_role.module_role: Refreshing state... [id=create-vault-entry-role]
module.lambda_iam.aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.lambda_attach: Refreshing state... [id=create-vault-entry-role-############################]
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
Terraform will perform the following actions:
  # module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.lambda_function will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
        id                             = "create-vault-entry"
      ~ last_modified                  = "2022-01-11T19:48:18.000+0000" -> (known after apply)
      ~ source_code_hash               = "g/hash/hash=" -> "hash/hash"
        tags                           = {}
        # (18 unchanged attributes hidden)
        # (2 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated
  on main.tf line 3, in locals:
   3:     vault_HOST = "${var.vault_HOST}",
Terraform 0.11 and earlier required all non-constant expressions to be
provided via interpolation syntax, but this pattern is now deprecated. To
silence this warning, remove the "${ sequence from the start and the }"
sequence from the end of this expression, leaving just the inner expression.
Template interpolation syntax is still used to construct strings from
expressions when the template includes multiple interpolation sequences or a
mixture of literal strings and interpolations. This deprecation applies only
to templates that consist entirely of a single interpolation sequence.
(and 5 more similar warnings elsewhere)
```

Comment: I would recommend moving everything to TF. This type of hybrid IaC is very prone to error.

Comment: @208_man What are the values for the `vpc_subnet_ids` and `vpc_security_group_ids` variables? Are they empty?

Comment: @208_man Does your `subnet_ids` & `security_group_ids` values are in `list(string)`?

Comment: @MarkoE, they are not empty.  They are lists of strings.

Comment: @Ravichandran, yes list(string)

Comment: @jellycsc, that is thought provoking.  I don't know if the VPC is maintained by another TF pipeline or was created manually.  What you're suggesting would imply that we centralize the maintenance of all our infrastructure components.  Which seems obvious now that I say it.

Comment: Any reason to use the old Terraform syntax with presumably newer Terraform version? Also, would you mind posting the values for both variables, omitting anything sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be converting lists to strings. The Lambda VPC `subnet_ids` and   `security_group_ids` attributes expect a list, not a string. I'm really not sure how your current code is working without any errors being reported.

It looks like you need to change this:

```
vpc_subnet_ids = "${var.SUBNET_IDS}"
vpc_security_group_ids = "${var.SECURITY_GROUP_IDS}"
```

To this:

```
vpc_subnet_ids = var.SUBNET_IDS
vpc_security_group_ids = var.SECURITY_GROUP_IDS
```

Comment: that was a great observation. Since these vars are of type `list(string)`, my bad syntax meant I was passing stringified lists.  But switching to correct syntax, as you suggested, didn't change the outcome. TF steps all pass, no VPC attachment in Lambda Configuration.  Puzzling!

Comment: What do you mean by "steps all pass"? Perhaps you should include the output of `terraform plan` in your question.

Comment: I guess I'm mixing terraform terms and gitlab ci terms.  My ci script runs terrform init, plan, apply, etc.  I added the output for terraform plan to my original question.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: I really don't think the Terraform code in your question is the code GitLab is running. Also, you should really be running `terraform plan` locally before even committing anything.

Comment: what is an example value of var.SUBNET_IDS?